# Unable to understand the following step in proving that $s_n$ has a limit iff $\lim \inf s_n = \lim \sup s_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Source: Elementary Analysis - The Theory Of Calculus by Kenneth A. Ross
The below steps are working on the "forward" implication of the iff statement, i.e if $\lim s_n$ is defined, then $\lim \inf s_n = \lim s_n = \lim \sup s_n$

> Suppose $\lim s_n = +\infty$. Let M be a positive real number. Then there exists a positive integer N so that $$n > N \implies s_n \gt M$$
> Then $u_N = \inf \{s_n : n>N\} \ge M.$

How do we know that $u_N \ge M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well each $s_n$ is certainly greater than $M$, as noted above by $n > N \implies s_n > M$. Then $u_N = \inf\{s_n \mid n > N \}$ is the greatest lower bound of those $s_n$; certainly $M$ is then a lower bound for the set $\{s_n \mid n > N \}$, so $u_N$ is at least $M$.